# Can the GPS in android emulator track my current position?

Tags: android-emulator

i have made a program to find the current location using GPS in android emulator that is working correctly , and is showing the correct latitudes and longitudes that i send from emulator control in eclipse, but is it possible that the GPS in the emulator could show my current location by itself , i.e. in a way track my location and show it by itself without having me to send it through the emulator control.

Here is the code:

```
package location.finder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LocationFinderActivity extends Activity {


 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LocationManager locationManager=   (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener locationListener = new loclistener();
      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);

  }

  public class loclistener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
        String loc ="Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() +" Longitude = " +  location.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),loc,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider , int status, Bundle extras)
    {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess in orinigal mobile you need not do any thing as it has GPS hardware
but emulator has GPS "stub" but it is not a real piece of hardware embedded in your PC so it will not track your location by itself
it would be better if you provide 
your "program to find the current location using GPS in android emulator that is working correctly , and is showing the correct latitudes and longitudes that i send from emulator control in eclipse"
so that we can see and tell further